# Google Maps API restricted to work on one domain but StreetView API is still accessible on other domains

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

So I just restricted by Google Maps API Key on the console. I added one authorized domain.

But somehow I am still able to access StreetView API using my key on other domains which are not on the list of authorized website.

I want this link to only be accessible when I run it on my domain and not on other domains or directly. Currently, when I run this directly on the browser it does not show a restriction warning: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=MYAPIKEYHERE

This also works when the page is hosted on another domain

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=MYAPIKEYHERE">
```

I only want this to work when it's on my authorized website.

Comment: How did you restrict the API Key?  Web services need to be restricted by IP address (per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem): IP addresses (individual servers) - for use with the web service APIs.)

Comment: I restricted using the HTTP Referrers option and added the domain name under the Website restrictions section

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that to work, I would expect it to give you a (somewhat) meaningful error message. But it doesn't seem to, it seems to return a response for any valid key that has the StreetView Static API allowed to use it.  Do you see hits on your key when you send it from the browser?

Comment: Yes, I do, I am forced to disable the StreetView Static API because the site has to go live. I'll revisit the problem later. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Start using a signature on all your requests and set your unsigned requests quota to zero.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key#gen_sig